# Way to avoid Express.Js behaviour of adding page url to file path

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am serving my front end code using `node.js` and `express.js`.

Here I'm facing an issue with my file path I provided in `script src` on different page URLs.

my project file structure is as follows:

```
react_jsx/
   dst/
      index.html
      styles.css
      main-62a2a28f9255e698905d.js  // creating this file using a bundler.
```

Both `styles.css` and `main-62a2a28f9255e698905d.js` are adding to `index.html` dynamically using `webpack` bundler. But adding correctly as
`<link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet"></head>` and `<script type="text/javascript" src="main-62a2a28f9255e698905d.js"></script>`

Node server code is as follows:

```
const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');

const app = express();


app.use(express.static(path.resolve(__dirname, 'react_jsx/dst')));
app.use(express.static(path.resolve(__dirname)));
// app.use('/react_jsx/dst',express.static(path.join(__dirname, '')));
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, ' ')));

app.get('*', (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, 'react_jsx/dst/index.html'));
});


const PORT = process.env.PORT || 9000;

app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`App listening on port ${PORT}!`);
});
```

The page is working fine on the base URL. ie., on `localhost:9000`.

But when I'm changing the page URL, the path to the files also changes. Suppose if the page Url is `localhost:9000/app/login` the path to my `styles.css` and `main-[hash].js` also changes.

The file path becoming `localhost:9000/app/login/styles.css` and `localhost:9000/app/login/main-[hash].js`

How can I resolve it? *I went through a lot of SO answers and resolved issue with some other file paths, but couldn't resolve issue with **files that located in the same folder of index.html***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give relative path from domain root in the html as shown below.

```
<link href="/style.css" rel="stylesheet"></head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/main-62a2a28f9255e698905d.js"></script>
```

Add this to the webpack config

```
output: {
    publicPath: "/"
}
```

Comment: As I mentioned in the question, these two `link` and `script` added dynamically using `webpack` bundler.

Comment: add the code where you are injecting styles and scripts dynamically using webpack

Comment: Hey, it worked like charm. Added output path. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

I think,you can use [routing](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/routing.html).

Like :

```
var router = express.Router();

app.use('/app/login', router);
```

Comment: I have a lot of URLs, Some are dynamic also. `/app/login` is just one among them